# Obtain Deviantart Deviation ID / UUID from page URL

Tags: api, deviation, deviantart-api

I was looking at the [Deviantart API](https://www.deviantart.com/developers/http/v1/20150217) to see what you can do with it .

A lot of requests require you to provide a deviation id to work with.
Take for instance adding a deviation to favorites ( in Collections -> Add deviation to favorites above, I cannot post more than 2 links... )

Now I looked through the API to figure out how to obtain that id, but I did not find out how to do so.

If I only have the deviation URL, for instance http://kennyklent.deviantart.com/art/Pinkie-Pie-Dancing-296143815 , how can I tell its deviation-id? 
It is not the number at the end `296143815`, I would've thought so, but it's not.

If it helps, here's one example from the api's `/browse/dailydeviations` endpoint

```
"deviationid": "27FD366A-30CB-FC3E-DE54-9621E90FCE60",
"printid": "E984FC87-8B57-239C-FE7C-E2674A0DDFC4",
"url": "http://mudimba.deviantart.com/art/SF-Botanical-Gardens-57879397",
```

So this deviation `SF-Botanical-Gardens-57879397` has the id `27FD366A-30CB-FC3E-DE54-9621E90FCE60` - but how would I find out if it wasn't listed in the examples?

Comment: The number at the end IS the deviation id, as a matter of fact. Also, +1 for the dancing pinkie. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update 06/2017:**

For anyone stumbling across this 2 years later, the answer below still works but there is now another way to get the UUID. Every Deviation now has a meta property `da:appurl` showing the UUID value on the deviation page itself.

To stay with the `SF-Botanical-Gardens-57879397` example from above, looking at the page source at http://mudimba.deviantart.com/art/SF-Botanical-Gardens-57879397 reveals:

```
<meta property="da:appurl" content="DeviantArt://deviation/27FD366A-30CB-FC3E-DE54-9621E90FCE60">
```

Which contains exactly the UUID value `27FD366A-30CB-FC3E-DE54-9621E90FCE60`

---

**Original answer**

I got an answer from a Deviantart dev directly, http://comments.deviantart.com/1/492518964/3755610860

> You cannot convert integer IDs into UUID format, you have to query the api to find the correct uuid. So for your example, you would query the /gallery/folders endpoint and then the gallery/{folderid} endpoint to get the list of deviations in that folder.

There's no easier way to obtain the UUID for a given URL for now.

Comment: So there isn't anyway to do it then. I really needed it for a filter system.

Comment: @JonathanJ.Pecany do none of the options work for your usecase?